# POST method on web api site receives null json

Tags: python, post, asp.net-web-api, attributes

I have a python client which suppose to get user details from DB through post web api call, however when i debug my web api the parameter i pass to the post method is null. From python site I'm passing dictionary serialized to json and web.api should receive it as a custom object called Credentials and use it to get data from DB and send it back.

I used C# client and everythink worked fine, json looks exactly the same.
I also tried restlet client and when i copy paste body value from python it works fine.

Python:

```
def CredentialsCheck(self,credentials):
    credentialsDictionary = { "Email": credentials.email, "Password": 
    credentials.password}
    data = json.dumps(credentialsDictionary)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

    request = requests.post(self.url,json = data,headers = headers)
    response = request.json()
    print(response)

creds = UserCredentials("n","s")

api = WebApiDataHandler()
api.CredentialsCheck(creds)
```

Obviously there is also **init**(self): where i set url

C# UI: - this one is working fine.

```
    public CalendarUser CredentialsCheck(CalendarUserCredentials credentials)
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            wc.Headers.Add("Data-Type", "application/json");
            string userJson = serializer.Serialize(credentials);
            string test = wc.BaseAddress + "GetUser" + userJson;
            CalendarUser loggedInUser = serializer.Deserialize<CalendarUser> 
    (wc.UploadString(wc.BaseAddress + "GetUser", "Post", userJson));
            if (loggedInUser.Name != "" && loggedInUser.Surname != "" && 
    loggedInUser.Name != null && loggedInUser.Surname != null)
                return loggedInUser;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect log in details.");
        }
```

C# web api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public CalendarUser GetUser([FromBody]CalendarUserCredentials credentials) //when i put breakpoint here it fires but value of CalendarUserCredentials is null
{
     CalendarUser user = new CalendarUser();
     dataHandler.CredentialsCheck(credentials, out user);
     return user;
}
```

I expect web api GetUser method to receive CalendarUserCredentials with values "n" for email and "s" for password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved the issue by changing CalendarUserCredentials into string and then deserializing this string although if someone has better solution please share it with me :)

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

[HttpPost]
        public CalendarUser GetUser([FromBody]string json)
        {
            CalendarUserCredentials credentials = serializer.Deserialize<CalendarUserCredentials>(json);
            CalendarUser user = new CalendarUser();
            dataHandler.CredentialsCheck(credentials, out user);
            return user;
        }
```

I would like to understand why it accepts json from C# and converts it correctly into CalendarUserCredentials but if I send the same json from Python it sees only null O.o